# Defining a CoffeeScript Hash Object using its own values in one motion

Tags: hash, coffeescript

Since I can't use the hash's values until they're defined, I was doing this:

```
@Foo =
  Protocol: "http"
  Domain:   "foo.com"

# Annoying...
@Foo.Url = "#{Foo.Protocol}://#{Foo.Domain}"
```

Ideally, I'd be doing something like this (one motion):

```
# Doesn't work obviously...

@Foo =
  Protocol: "http"
  Domain:   "foo.com"
  Url:      "#{Foo.Protocol}://#{Foo.Domain}"
```

Is there any way to do this?

The best methods I can come up with are:

**Using Closures**

```
@Foo = do =>
  protocol = "http"
  domain   = "foo.com"
  url      = "#{protocol}://#{domain}"

  protocol: protocol
  domain:   domain
  url:      url
```

**Using $.extend**

```
$.extend @Foo =
  protocol: "http"
  domain:   "foo.com"
,
  url: "#{Foo.protocol}://#{Foo.domain}"
```

Thanks,

Erik

Comment: Could you make them all functions instead of properties? CS wraps everything in a SIF scope wrapper so you could things [like this](http://coffeescript.org/#try:p%20%3D%20'http'%0Ad%20%3D%20'foo.com'%0A%40Foo%20%3D%0A%20%20Protocol%3A%20p%0A%20%20Domain%3A%20%20%20d%0A%20%20Url%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%23%7Bp%7D%3A%2F%2F%23%7Bd%7D%22) without polluting the global scope.

Comment: @muistooshort With the `do ->` closure, my example shouldn't pollute the global scope.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just saying that if `@Foo` is the only thing in the file then you can get the same effect without the `do`.

Comment: Ah, gottcha.  It's a relatively large file but that's good to know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use functions instead of properties.

```coffeescript
@Foo =
  Protocol: -> "http"
  Domain:   -> "foo.com"
  Url:      -> "#{this.Protocol()}://#{this.Domain()}"

@Foo.Url() == "http://foo.com"
```

Or, if you wanted to use regular javascript, you could use a getter

```js
Foo = {
  Protocol: 'http',
  Domain:   'foo.com',
  get Url() {
    return this.Protocol + '://' + this.Domain;
  }
}

Foo.Url == 'http://foo.com'

Foo.Protocol = 'https'

Foo.Url == 'https://foo.com'
```